# Как сделать разграничение ролей в Django

Tags: django

Существует модель User подгружаемая с БД, в этой модели есть атрибут - кем является юзер (преподаватель, студент, модератор). Как далее можно сделать, чтобы у каждого юзера был разный функционал/доступ к функционалу?

Comment: Ну, банально `if user.атрибут == преподаватель` и так далее, наверное?

Comment: спасибо! тогда как нужно будет сделать, чтобы студент, например, не видел кнопку создания, а не просто не имел к ней доступа?

Comment: Ну, банально `if user.атрибут != студент: нарисовать_кнопку_создания()` и так далее, наверное?

Comment: кнопка рисуется в html шаблоне, разве туда можно добавить условие?

Comment: Ну, банально `{% if user.атрибут != студент %}<button>Создание</button>{% endif %}` и так далее, наверное?  https://dev-gang.ru/article/ispolzovanie-if-else-v-django-shablonah-fsxwrffzyp/

Comment: Спасибо большое!